# My world doesn't have a Jungle biome?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I explored my entire Minecraft world and I couldn't find a jungle biome. I really want pandas and bamboo. I know I can get bamboo by fishing, but it takes a long time to get as much as I need. I know I can go on creative but my world is a survival world and I don't want to go into creative.

If anyone has a seed with a jungle biome can you give it to me?

I am playing the PlayStation 4 Edition of Minecraft.

Comment: What version are you playing on? Worlds should be infinite which means you have a jungle biome somewhere.

Comment: Playstation 4 edition

Comment: You might have to travel tens of thousands of blocks until you find one, they're rare.

Comment: Yeah. However, he says he explored the entire world, which makes me think it isn't infinite, like old world in pocket edition. However, he wants a seed that spawns with a jungle biome in it.

Comment: A quick Google/Bing/Firefox/Edge/whatever search should yield a bunch of seeds for a jungle biome. It's up to you to take your pick.

Comment: @Robbie The legacy console edition of minecraft, which this question is tagged as, has finite worlds.

Comment: I asked that because when first asked it has the Minecraft tag instead of the Minecraft-Console tag @pppery

Answer (score 2):

Bamboo can be grown once you got a single piece by fishing, just plant it into the ground and you will have plenty in a matter of minutes.

Next the jungle saplings can be bought by wandering traders if you are lucky, same for cocoa beans.

As for the Panda/parrot/ocelot I have no idea if that is possible I do think they can only spwan there and there is no way to make them spawn otherwise without using spawneggs aka creative mode.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are you do have a jungle biome in your world, sometimes biomes can be very hard to find. In my world the closest jungle is 6k blocks away from spawn, sometimes you can just get very unlucky.

Although there are [seed mappers](http://mineatlas.com/) where you can see the layout of the biomes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will eventually find one if your world is infinite but they are extremely rare.
If you don't mind starting a new world set it to infinite then creative then fly around until you find one and set the world to survival.

Comment: as of now a world in any version but the Java Version of Minecraft won't have infinite worlds.